# Hosting WCF Services in ASP.NET MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, integration

I have an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 webapp, which serves as a front-end site for our external API. More specifically, it has a Control Panel for our API clients, documentation, etc.

Now I want to move our actual API (which is a set of WCF services) inside this project, so that, for example, `http://api.example.com/controlpanel/dashboard` would be served by ASP.NET MVC runtime, wherease `http://api.example.com/services/1.0/users.svc` would be served by an appropriate WCF service.

Granted, this can be done by adding a `services/1.0` virtual folder in IIS, but I *really* want these two parts to be inside one project.

Is this doable at all? If yes, how do I integrate these two beasts?

Comment: Looks like I'm onto something: [Hosting WCF Side-by-Side with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx).

Comment: That appears to talk about ASP.NET applications, rather than ASP.NET MVC applications. In particular, I'm interested in how you get WCF to play nicely with routing in MVC.

Comment: I've started a bounty on this as I want to do the same thing. Hopefully someone knows the answer to save me searching for it :)

Comment: You probably just want to add an ignore route for your WCF paths.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out MVC/WCF isn't the issue.  Services hosted within the MVC app are activated just fine (I guess IIS bypasses the MVC runtime for .svc requests).

The issue was more to do with services in Areas, and requests for .svc files not going through the route table.

I've asked a more specific question addressing the actual problem here.

[Expose WCF services that belong to an Area in MVC app at a routed path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047485/expose-wcf-services-that-belong-to-an-area-in-mvc-app-at-a-routed-path)