# Expose WCF services that belong to an Area in MVC app at a routed path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've got a WCF service (lets say `TestService.svc` sitting inside the `services` directory of an Area in an MVC app.  This area is combined into the main app.  The area is called `content`.

The routes have been setup and the area works fine.  To access the `Index` action on the `Home` controller I can do either:

`http://my-host/areas/content/index/home`

or

`http://my-host/content/index/home`

The SVC file however can only be accessed via:

`http://my-host/areas/content/services/TestService.svc`

The URL must include the `areas` directory, I can't access it directly via `http://my-host/content/services/TestService.svc`.  If I try I am given an error 404.

Is there a way to setup the application so that it routes the SVC request through the same route table as the controllers?  I don't want to have to use `areas` for the services.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have the liberty to use .Net 4.0 you might want to consider making your WCF service available via a [ServiceRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.serviceroute.aspx) rather than via a .svc file.

This will enable you to avoid having the TestService.svc file with a TestService.svc.cs code-behind. In your Global.asax.cs you will have the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, IUnityContainer container)
{
    ... other MVC route mapping ....
    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("TestService", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LoaEvents)));
}
```

Your service should then be accessible via `http://my-host/TestService`.

You might be able to change the `"TestService"` argument to `"/content/services/TestService"` or something that works better for your needs.

Comment: As a side note, you can't start route paths with a forward slash, so it'd be `content/services/TestService`.

Comment: I was able to use this solution after applying the route constraint as in http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/09/22/wcf-rest-services-inside-mvc-projects.aspx

Comment: i just saved my life