# ASP.NET MVC service route overrides default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added WCF service to MVC 5 application, and created a route for it:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1.svc", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The problem is that all my links leads to the Service1.svc route now. `@Html.ActionLink("Passport Maker", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })` become `http://localhost:50099/Service1.svc?action=Index&controller=Home` and other links change in the same way.

If I add ServiceRoute after "Default" route, the links work correctly but the service is unavailable.

Why it happens (there is no "Service1" in the links, why they select the service route then?) and how to fix it?

Comment: Please refer this [link][1]

This will help to resolve your problem.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938746/hosting-a-wcf-service-in-an-mvc-application-outside-of-areas

Comment: @JineshJain thanks, it lead me to the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = "^(?!Service1.svc).*" }
);

routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1.svc", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
```

Explanations for those who may encounter a similar problem: the reason of the problem was that `Html.ActionLink` uses the first matching route to generate the link. And my service route was the first and was matching, because a route does not require to include `{controller}` and `{action}` parameters to be matched (as I thought initially).

The solution is to put the default route first, so it is used by `Html.ActionLink`. And to still be able to use the service route, need to exclude it from the the first route using constraints. The regex `^(?!Service1.svc).*` matches only those controller names that don't start from "Service1.svc".